# Receiving the error "Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation" from Playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, playwright

I have built a small helper function to try and help make the nested loops easier to read/write in my playwright script but I am now encountering this error.

Since I am using async/await I am not sure why or where the navigation is continuing before I have a chance to execute the code.

I can write out the utility function manually and it seems to work but creating it as a function generates this error.

In addition to the error itself I wouldn't mind any pointers or suggestions on improvements / learnings to the code and approach.

**Utility Function**

```
loopOverLocators: async (locator, callback) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < await locator.count(); i++) 
        {
            callback(locator.nth(i))
        }
    }
```

**Main File**

```
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ override: true })
import { createOutputFile, getInputFromHeader, loopOverLocators } from '../helpers/utils'
import paths from '../get-paths'

const USERNAME = process.env.USERNAME
const PASSWORD = process.env.PASSWORD

const filename = "all-test-entities.csv"
const headers = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(paths.helpers_dir, 'get-headers.json'), 'utf-8'))
const countries = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(paths.helpers_dir, 'get-countries.json'), 'utf-8'))
const file = createOutputFile(filename)

test("Output all test entities to CSV file", async ({ page }) => {

    let test_entities = []

    await page.goto('https://adminportal.trulioo.com/Account/LogOn');
    await page.locator('#UserName').click();
    await page.locator('#UserName').fill(USERNAME);
    await page.locator('#Password').click();
    await page.locator('#Password').fill(PASSWORD);
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign In' }).click();
    await page.frameLocator('#duo_iframe').getByRole('button', { name: 'Send Me a Push' }).click();

    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Admin Portal' }).click();
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Global', exact: true }).click();
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Manage Default Test Entities' }).click();

    for (const country_option of countries.options)
    {
        console.log("Entered " + country_option)
        await page.locator('#SelectedConfiguration').selectOption(country_option);
        await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'View Test Entities' }).click();
        await page.waitForSelector('.default-test-entity')

        // loop over `.default-test-entity locators`
        const test_entity_locators = page.locator('.default-test-entity')
        loopOverLocators(test_entity_locators, async (test_entity) => {
            console.log(await test_entity)
        })
    }
})
```

**ERROR**

```
Error: locator.count: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation

       at ..\helpers\utils.js:38

      36 |     },
      37 |     loopOverLocators: async (locator, callback) => {
    > 38 |         for (let i = 0; i < await locator.count(); i++)
         |                                           ^
      39 |         {
      40 |             callback(locator.nth(i))
      41 |         }

        at loopOverLocators (C:\Development\create-test-entities\helpers\utils.js:38:43)
```

I've tried to add additional async/awaits within the utility function and main script to see if I could get the script to wait for the code to run before proceeding on with the navigation.

I can remove the utility function and manually write out the for loops for each iteration but I want to figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await` and callbacks, generally. There's no need for this function--just move the loop to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You could await all locators with the [all()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-all) method and eventually pass the array to the helper function (which in my opinion, does not help readability):

```js
test('Test', async ({ page }) => {
    // Ref. documentation, make sure that the page is loaded before 
    // doing all(), by e.g. using waitForLoadState
    await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
    const test_entity_locators = await page.locator('.default-test-entity').all()
    
    // Do it directly
    for (const entity of test_entity_locators) {
        console.log(entity)
    }

    // ...or by using a helper function
    await loopOverLocators(test_entity_locators)
})

const loopOverLocators = async (locatorArray: Locator[]) => {
    for (const entity of locatorArray) {
        console.log(entity)
    }
}
```